# GCM implement failed

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have big problem. 
I create server api-key like at google documentation. Create IntentService and BroadcastReceiver. I put my RegistrationId on my server, but I don't receive push-message from google server.
This my code, can you tell me, what I do wrong?
IntentService:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
Context context;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

public GcmIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);//"GcmIntentService");//
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

     if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

         if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                sendNotification(msg);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
     GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            //new Intent(this, BaseActivity.class), 0);
            myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

BroadCast:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);


}
```

}

manifest:

```
package="*.*"
android:versionCode="329"
android:versionName="1.0.3"
android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="*.*.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="*.*.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>



    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <receiver
        android:name="*.*.cgm.GcmBroadcastReceiverCompat"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="*.*.cgm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".screens.StartingActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </activity>       

<service android:name="*.*.cgm.GcmIntentService" />
...
```

Best Regards.

Comment: *.*.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE where * indiactes your package name right?

Comment: yes, I checked it 5 times %)

Answer (score 1):

If your app's package is `*.*`, the permissions should be :

```
<permission android:name="*.*.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="*.*.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

(without `gcm`)

The category in the broadcast receiver should also be without `gcm` :

```
<category android:name="*.*" />
```

And if your intent service class is in *.*.gcm while your app's package is *.* the following code won't work, since it will look for the intent service in the main package :

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
        GcmIntentService.class.getName());
```

You should replace it with :

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(GCMIntentService.class.getPackage().getName(),
        GcmIntentService.class.getName());
```

Comment: I fix it all
package="com.patsy"
<permission android:name="com.patsy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.patsy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />  
android:name="com.patsy.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
<category android:name="com.patsy" />
<service android:name="megaf.universe.gcm.GcmIntentService"/>

but it didn't help me

Comment: @PatsyPatsy Did you change the `ComponentName comp = ...` line too?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using onMessage Overridden method, you may receive.
2. Try creating Browser key instead of Android Key in Google API console and use it.
3. Use com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver instead of *.*.cgm.GcmBroadcastReceiverCompat

Thanks this may help you.

Comment: When I create package, I confused name:) - cgm

I fix my manifest, but it don't help me.

Comment: package="com.example"
 <permission android:name="com.example.cgm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.cgm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  android:name="com.example.cgm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"